# Check the fist item of my ListView

Tags: android, listview

**Aim (part 3):** Check if the first element of my `listview`  is completely displayed in the top of my activity

**From 1 -> 2 :** i hide my slider with the bellow code

**From 3 -> 1 :** How can i do it ?

**R.id.main_activity_linear_layout :** contain my SlideImagefragment

```
// Comment ...

    public class ActualiteFragment extends ListFragment {

    ...


     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_activity_linear_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            try{
                if(getListView().getChildAt(0).getTop()==0){
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_activity_linear_layout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }       
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e){

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't tried. Probably the below code will help you.

override the onSCroll method

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //Check if the first view is visible
        if(lv.getChildAt(0).getX()<0){
          lv.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleItem+1);
        }
    }
});
```